# Error connecting to Redis Server from Node.js on Amazon AWS EC2 server

Tags: database, node.js, amazon-ec2, redis

I am trying to run a node.js server and a Redis server on an Amazon AWS Ec2 micro instance .

I have installed Redis Server and the redis-server command runs fine .

I use '[Forever](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever)' to keep the Redis-Server running . And it works fine .

But when I start my Node server , it fails to connect to the Redis-Server .

It gives the following error -

```
Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
```

Doing a 'Forever List' shows that the redis server is running fine .

```
info:   Forever processes running
data:       uid  command script                         forever pid   logfile                        uptime          
data:   [0] _pXw node    app.js                         26670   26671 /home/ubuntu/.forever/_pXw.log 0:0:0:13.463    
data:   [1] ylT1 node    redis-server                   25013   26681
```

I have verified that when the redis-server starts , it starts at 6379 port .

Can anyone help me explain why this error is happening and how I fix this ?

I use the following code to connect to Redis . I have the client libraries installed for Redis .

```
var redis = require("redis"),
        client = redis.createClient();
```

Everything runs fine when I run the code on my localhost .

Comment: Have you checked the redis client-server connection on AWS using the ping-pong routine. Next maybe you should try running it without forever, as root.

Comment: Thanks almypal. I tried the ping pong test and the test  failed. Next I ran it as root without using forever . The test worked. Now my node.js app also connects fine . Do you think the problem was this forever ? My problem is solved as of now . If you post your response as answer, I will accept it . Thanks !

Comment: An unrelated question . As per ur instruction, I ran redis-server in the background by 'sudo redis-server & ' . Now how do I stop the redis-server ? Issuing  a 'ps' command doesnt list the redis-server .So I cant get the PID to kill it . 'Fg' command has no effect as well.

Comment: On Ubuntu you could use sudo fuser -v 5000/tcp to check the service running at port 5000 and then use sudo fuser -vk 5000/tcp to kill the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the redis client-server connection on AWS using the ping-pong routine. Next maybe you should try running it without forever, as root.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use Redis outside of AWS you can try next steps that helped me to connect Redis Server working on AWS from my local Nodejs application:

1) On AWS: **sudo cp /etc/redis/redis.conf.backup /etc/redis/redis.conf**. Backup saves you a lot of energy figuring out whats wrong :)

2) On AWS: stop redis-server: **sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server stop**

3) On AWS: open /etc/redis/redis.conf and find a line **bind 127.0.0.1**. Copy and paste new line below **bind 0.0.0.0**. So you could have several lines with **bind** parameter. BTW, **port** of connection can be changed in redis.conf as well

4) On AWS: start redis-server: **sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start**

5) On AWS: type **redis-cli ping** you should see **PONG** message if redis-server started ok

6) On AWS: Now open Sequrity Group for your running isntance and add New Rule with "Type" - Custom TCP Rule, Port Range - 6379

7) In your local Nodejs application:

`var redis = require("redis");

var redisClient = redis.createClient(redis_port, redis_host);`

[nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) [redis](/questions/tagged/redis)  [aws](/questions/tagged/aws)